# Create a new df column using a function where the inputs are df columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, calculated-columns

I have a df with 2 columns (A, B)
I also have a function sd = sd.(input 1, input 2).

I would like to create a new df col, where

df["newcolumn"] = sd.(df(A), df(B))

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

```
df[newcolumn] = sd.(df.apply["A"], df.apply["B"])
```

error = name 'applydf' is not defined.